# The meaning of 住んでる星が違う

Tags: colloquial-language

The sentence is "諸星先生は元々住んでる星が違うし". This looks to me an idiomatic expression, but I cannot find this in dictionary.

Another interpretation I was thinking about is that the teacher in the above sentence "lives in another star/solar system", which is to say that it's just a completely different person (in character). It fits, but not sure if it is accurate; for one, living in another planet feels more accurate, and if so 星 should be short for 惑星？

Comment: Related: [Is there any word for stars only?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48837/5010)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 「諸星先生{もろほしせんせい}は元々住{もともとす}んでる星{ほし}が違{ちが}うし・・」

While 「住んでる星が違う」 is certainly an exaggerated and/or metaphorical expression, I would not necessarily call it an idiomatic expression because it means what it literally means, which is "**to live on another planet**" as you said.

「星」 can mean "a planet" as well all by itself.

> "Mr./Ms. Morohoshi lives on another planet to begin with."

A super-literal TL would be:

"As for Mr./Ms. Morohoshi, the planet s/he originally lives on is different."

This is a good example of how literal translation rarely works well between the two languages.  What I am trying to say is that if you translated the very natural-sounding English phrase "to live on another planet" directly into Japanese, you would ***not*** arrive at 「住んでる星が違う」, which is a completely natural-sounding Japanese phrase.

Comment: I think a more natural English phrase is "he lives in a different world"

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any context, so I can't be 100% sure, but the super short answer is probably that the speaker is trying to say that Mr./Ms. Morohoshi has a completely different set of values than those around him, which makes him stand out and appear quirky or possibly mildly insane.